# I am getting the following error for difference of sum of diagonals

Tags: java, list, arraylist, difference, diagonal

**I am trying to find the sum of difference of a 2D array diagonal.**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Result
{

  public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) 
  {
    int d1=0,d2=0;
    int res;

    for(int i=0; i<=arr.size(); i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
      {
        if(i==j)
        {
          d1 = d1+arr.get(i,j);
        }
        if(i==arr.size()-j-1)
        {
          d2 = d2+arr.get(i,j);
        }
      }
    }
    res=d1-d2;
    return res;
  }
}
```

```
public class Solution
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

    int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

    List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      String[] arrRowTempItems = bufferedReader.readLine()
                                   .replaceAll("\\s+$", "")
                                   .split(" ");

      List<Integer> arrRowItems = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
        int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrRowTempItems[j]);
        arrRowItems.add(arrItem);
      }
      arr.add(arrRowItems);
    }

    int result = Result.diagonalDifference(arr);

    bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
    bufferedWriter.newLine();

    bufferedReader.close();
    bufferedWriter.close();
  }
}
```

> `Solution`.java:29: error: method `get` in `interface List<E>` cannot be
>   applied to given types;
>
> ```
>               `d1 = d1+arr.get(i,j);`
>                        ^  required: `int`
> ```
>
> found: `int`,`int`
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>
> where `E` is a type-variable:
>
> `E` extends `Object` declared in `interface List`
>
> Solution.java:33: error: method get in `interface List<E>` cannot be
>   applied to given types;
>
> ```
>             `d2 = d2+arr.get(i,j);`
>                      ^ required: int
> ```
>
> found: `int`,`int`
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>
> where `E` is a type-variable:    `E` extends `Object` declared in `interface List`

Comment: `get` applies to a single index, which in your case will return you a list of Integers that you can then `get` from. Probably what you want is not `.get(1, 2)` but `.get(1).get(2)`

Comment: There is no point in iterating all is and js. Given an i, you can calculate the corresponding js where you need to increment the sums.

Comment: use .get(i).get(j)

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the method `diagonalDifference` like below:

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) 
{
    int d1=0,d2=0;
    int res;

    int size = arr.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {

        d1 += arr.get(i).get(i);
        d2 += arr.get(i).get(size - i -1);

    }
    res=d1-d2;
    return res;
}
```

You don't need a `List<List<Integer>>` because from your code you are defining an int[][] array that will no more modified, so you could pass instead the `int[][] array` defined previously.